# python-nvd3 two and more graphs on a page

Tags: python, d3.js, beautifulsoup, nvd3.js

thanks to python-nvd3 I can produce beautiful interactive graphs! But, Id like to put two graphs on a single page. So far I figure out how to manually concatenate  two python-nvd3 generated html files. (And now thinking about python script to automate it, but hoping there is a shortcut) How to do it automatically in python-nvd3?

I wanna get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BulFS.png

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem by hand, thanks to Beautiful Soup. In python-nvd3 I generate HTML plots, than I parse them with Beautiful Soup, and append bodies elements from all plots to the first one, and write it to disk. Just a couple of lines.

btw, very handy thing for html parsing:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to place same type of charts on same page because they have same id i.e. they will over-right each other. For me, I simply replaced id with some unique id. For example, say I have multiple lineCharts, I do something like to the generated script:

```
linechart_script1.replace('data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline', 'data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline_1')

linechart_script2.replace('data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline', 'data_linechart_with_interactive_guideline_2')
```